# "A dog" or "the dog" or "dogs" ... which to use when speaking in general terms about dogs

Tags: definite-article, indefinite-article, zero-article

Could you tell me all the possibilities of interpretation of this sentence.

I like a dog.

I know we should put "dogs".

But sometimes I find some books say "I like a dog."

Or like
A dog is ~~~(general things).

Answer (score 4):

I think you are being confused by the word 'like'.

When using it as a verb:

> I like chocolate.
>
> My mother likes to travel.

When using it as an adjective:

> Just like a dog can be trained to hunt, a pigeon can be trained to race.

Definitions of [like](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/like) (MW):

verb

> to feel attraction toward or take pleasure in

adjective:

> the same or nearly the same

As to your specific question, the phrase:

> I like a dog

is not clear whether it's grammatical or not.  We need more context.

This sentence is not grammatical:

> I like a dog.

But this sentence is grammatical:

> I like a dog that doesn't bark too much.

And this sentence is grammatical:

> I like dogs.

Comment: How about "I like dogs that don't bark too much"? is it grammatical as well?

Comment: @Will Yes, that's also grammatical

Comment: "I like a dog" is as grammatical as "I like a girl" or "I like a shot of rum" ...

Comment: @Robusto I thought about that.  "I like a dry martini."  But it sounds odd to me w.r.t 'dog' for some reason.

Comment: @JohnFeltz "sounds odd" isn't the same as "not grammatical". Grammatically is higher standard. It's grammatical but not likely to be used except perhaps in specific contexts

Comment: @John: That doesn't make it ungrammatical. Even nonsense can be grammatical.. See [Colorless green ideas sleep furiously](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Colorless_green_ideas_sleep_furiously).

Comment: Thank you for reply. And I'm not confused. Sorry I might no be clear. What I wanted to say is that in what kind of context is just "I like a dog." used.